# Is there a dataset for the flow of people?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, time-series, telecom

**Data**: I am looking for an anonymised dataset for the flow of people I suppose one may know about it with the cell site or towers. I woul be especifically glad to get geojsons.

**Context**: I am looking for this to test the hypothesis that the biggest the flows the higher criminal rate you get.

**Region**:  in London, Paris or other big cities.

**Format**: I have a preference for geojson. Otherwise anything

Comment: My first impression is that this is highly unlikely to be available as open data given privacy concerns.  Perhaps you can review some of the literature on the uses of human movement data to identify sources.

Comment: Perhaps look into what Uber does. They have some info on their dev pages. Also, wayz.

Comment: @not2qubit that's a good idead ! I looked up but didn't found anything ...

Comment: Mayebe [this](http://rocs.hu-berlin.de/corona/docs/data/) can help. There they have obtained a flux, but it's not clear from where or how the data was imported.